# Перенос текста в Label

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.geometry('600x400')
label = Label(root, text='аааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа', 
              font='Georgia') #74
label.grid(row=0, column=0)
```

В переменной `label` хранится 74 "а", это предел (учитывая шрифт и разрешение `600x400`), дальше символы уходят за экран. Так вот, помогите мне сделать так, чтобы символы не уходили за экран, а переносились на другую строку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант можно получить фактическую ширину текста, посчитать примерную ширину символа, посчитать сколько символов поместится в нужной ширине окна, потом с помощью функции [`wrap` из модуля `textwrap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.wrap) разбить на строки и вывести текст в `label` еще раз:

```
from tkinter import *
from textwrap import wrap

root = Tk()
root.geometry('600x400')

text = 'a'*74

label = Label(root, text=text, font='Georgia')
label.grid(row=0, column=0)

# Принудительно обновляем интерфейс,
# чтобы появилось окно и можно было получить фактическую ширину текста:
root.update()  

width = label.winfo_width()

if width > 600:
    char_width = width / len(text)
    wrapped_text = '\n'.join(wrap(text, int(600 / char_width)))
    label['text'] = wrapped_text

root.mainloop()
```

[image: Скриншот]

Функция `wrap` также корректно делает перенос по словам:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

В некоторых случаях текст может выходить за границы экрана, т.к. в строке может оказаться много символов, ширина которых больше средней рассчитанной (для моноширинных шрифтов такой проблемы нет). Чтобы решить эту проблему, можно в цикле уменьшать количество символов, по которому будет проходить перенос, пока текст не станет помещаться:

```
text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod " \
"tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, " \
"quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea  commodo " \
"consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse " \
"cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non " \
"proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

label = Label(root, text=text, font='Georgia')
label.grid(row=0, column=0)

# Принудительно обновляем интерфейс,
# чтобы появилось окно и можно было получить фактическую ширину текста:
root.update()  

if label.winfo_width() > root.winfo_width():
    # Вычисляем среднюю ширину символа
    average_char_width = label.winfo_width() / len(text)
    # Приблизительно рассчитываем количество символов, которое помещается в окне
    chars_per_line = int(root.winfo_width() / average_char_width)
    # В цикле уменьшаем это количество, пока текст не станет помещаться
    while label.winfo_width() > root.winfo_width():  
        wrapped_text = '\n'.join(wrap(text, chars_per_line))
        label['text'] = wrapped_text
        root.update()
        chars_per_line -= 1
```

Результат без коррекции (во второй строке выход за границы окна):
[image]
Результат с коррекцией:
[image]

Comment: Спасибо, но что-то я не совсем понял, какую функцию выполняет переменная `width`, но я так понимаю, что в ней хранится ширина переменной `label`, затем в переменной `char_width` мы ищем длину последнего символа в `label`, а с помощью переменной `wrapped_text` мы переносим строку. Но, я не совсем понимаю как работает функция `wrap`, смотрел документацию по модулю, но тоже ничего не понял..

Comment: `width` - фактическая ширина текста в пикселях. `char_width` - средняя ширина символа в пикселях (общая ширина в пикселях делить на количество символов). `wrap` разбивает текст на список строк не больше указанной длины в символах. Пытается разбить по пробелам, если не получается - разбивает посредине слова (как разбила серию букв а в первом случае).