# Пропадание виджетов в tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, wikipedia

Делаю приложение в котором можно быстро найти информацию в википедии.
При вводе запроса и нажатия на кнопку "Искать" появляется криво текст(не весь) и пропадают другие виджеты.
Можно ли как то сделать перенос по строкам тексту и вернуть виджеты?

```
import wikipedia
from tkinter import *

def search_article():
    entrytext = format(txtentry.get())  
    article_text.configure(text=wikipedia.summary(entrytext, sentences=3))  

wikipedia.set_lang("ru")
window = Tk()
window.title("WikiPy")
window.geometry('700x500') 

txtentry = Entry(window, width=10)
txtentry.grid(column=1, row=0)

btn = Button(window, text="Искать", command=search_article)
btn.grid(column=3, row=0)

article_text = Label(window, text="")
article_text.grid(column=0, row=5)


window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас в `Label` каждый абзац текста добавляется в одну строку, из-за этого `Label` растягивается по ширине максимально, и вытесняет другие виджеты за границы окна. Вообще, `Label` не имеет встроенного способа вывода текста с переносом по словам (хотя, при желании его можно сделать: [Перенос строки Label tkinter](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1168791/1365)). Проще использовать виджет `Text`:

```
import wikipedia
from tkinter import *


def search_article():
    entrytext = txtentry.get()
    article_text.delete(1.0, END)
    article_text.insert(END, wikipedia.summary(entrytext, sentences=3))


wikipedia.set_lang("ru")
window = Tk()
window.title("WikiPy")
window.geometry('700x500')

txtentry = Entry(window, width=10)
txtentry.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=EW)

btn = Button(window, text="Искать", command=search_article)
btn.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky=W)

article_text = Text(window, wrap=WORD)
article_text.grid(column=0, row=1, columnspan=2)

window.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]